# Node.js & Redis get key data

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, redis

I read a lot about this problem but I can't solve it. I'm working in a code in node.js and redis to get the data from a key. Of course, when I execute client.get it  prints data as nul or undefined because of async. But I don't know how to solve it.

Example code: this part works fine

```
     pubsub.on('psubscribe', function() {
            while(i<end){
                client.set( i , url, function() {
                });
                client.expire( i , 10);
                   console.log("New key: " + i);
                i++;
                }
    });
```

Then, when the key expires I want to get de data to set it again in Redis:

```
    pubsub.on('pmessage', function(channel, message) {
        var keyData;
        client.get(message, function(err,data){
          keyData = data;
        });
        client.set( message , keyData, function(){});
        client.expire( message , 10);

    });
```

Of course, data is null.

How can I solve it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what do you exactly want to do? Data will expire in redis if you set a expiry time? why are you trying to get it?  you can very well store the data somewhere in your program and set it again

Comment: @DKG basically he was getting keyData as null in client.set because the callback had not yet reached :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because node is async in nature. Here is something that might help you out.

```
client.get(message,(err,data)=>{
  client.set( message , data,()=>{
    client.expire( message , 10);
  });
});
```

This being said, it is a bad implementation and would lead to `callback hell`. A better implementation using promise would be

```
var clientGet = (message)=>{
  return new Promise((fullfill,reject)=>{
    client.get(message,(err,data)=>{
      if(err)
        reject(err);
      else
        fullfill([message,data]);
    });
  });
}


var clientSet = (dataFromGet)=>{
  return new Promise((fullfill,reject)=>{
    let message,data = dataFromGet;
    client.set(message,data,()=>{
      fullfill(message);
    });
  });
}


var clientExpire = (message)=>{
  return new Promise((fullfill,reject)=>{
    client.expire(message,10);
    fullfill();
  });
}
```

And you can call them using

```
clientGet(message)
  .then(clientSet)
  .then(clientExpire)
  .then(()=>{
    console.log("All operations were fine");
  })
  .catch((ex)=>{
    console.err(ex.message);
  });
```

#### Why not to use first method

As i wrote previously it would lead to `callback hell` which is basically a lot of callbacks inside one another. As you can see from the first part of the code that there were two functions, they might increase and usually makes the code more difficult to manage and read.

Comment: Hi georoot, I try it and it returns me the next error:
`All operations were fine
node_redis: Deprecated: The EXPIRE command contains a "undefined" argument.
This is converted to a "undefined" string now and will return an error from v.3.0 on.
Please handle this in your code to make sure everything works as you intended it to.`

Seems to be undefined again.